# How to mkdir with React-Native-FS

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying to add functionality to my RN app that will allow users to create a new directory within their phone's file system.

I have tried to write the code so that the function creates a directory in the path /storage/emulated/0/AppName/NewFolder, since /storage/emulated/0 is the same path that is used by other apps I use to store user data (such as recording apps)

```
    makeDirectory = () => {
        const { currentFolder, units } = this.props;

        const directoryName = 'New Folder'
        const currentDirectory = units

        const absolutePath = `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/${currentDirectory}`

        RNFS.mkdir(absolutePath)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('result', result)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.warn('err', err)
            })
    }
```

However, this is just giving me an error: directory could not be created. I feel I am missing something here, and am not supposed to be saving the files like this to the phone's system.

My ultimate goal is to have the app with it's own folder system that will be mirrored within /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/home

Answer (score 7):

```
 const    AppFolder    =     'DirNameyouwant';
 const DirectoryPath= RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +'/'+ AppFolder;
 RNFS.mkdir(DirectoryPath);
```

Comment: While your code may answer the question, it's often useful to include an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried out and my folder is created successfully.

**use**

```
const absolutePath = `/storage/emulated/0/${currentDirectory}`
```

**instead**

```
const absolutePath = `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/${currentDirectory}`
```

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, In android 11, i am unable to create director with both permission and  other configurations. Have you create a directory in external storage of android 11???

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask permission from the user for accessing his phone storage.

See this comment by [Lylest](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/677#issuecomment-633204198) on [this](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/677) reported issue from GitHub

Answer (score 0):

> I have resolved my issue by adding this line in the Android Manifest
> file

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"