# How to add a folder to gallery in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'd like to add a folder to the gallery in React Native, like Instagram or WhatsApp have one.
Could you tell me how to do that in React Native for Android and iOS ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408709/how-to-mkdir-with-react-native-fs

Comment: Not exactly. I used this answer to create my folder on my device but I don't have a folder in Gallery. The picture I save doesn't appear in Gallery

Comment: Reboot your device.

Comment: You're right, reboot my device was the solution. Thank you